# Altering which class is instantiated based off initialization parameters

Tags: oop, python

What is the best way to vary what class is instantiated based off parameters to an initialization function in Python? For example, for a quadtree, if the number of elements is below a certain threshold, you want to return a leaf rather than a branch. Another example would be a graph which can either be backed by a adjacency matrix or list depending on what data it is initialized with.

The most obvious way I can think to do this is with a factory function that determines which subclass of the class in question should be initialized. Is there a better, more pythonic 
way of going about this?

In one particularly tricky instance of this problem, I had a data structure that could be backed by any kind of sequence or dict type. The backing/subclass used depended on the type of the data that it was fed. In a statically typed language, I could simply have used function overloading, but in Python I was left to either explicitly call isinstance, or use a bunch of "try...catch AttributeError"s. Both of these seem like quite bad practice. Using the factory function solution above, I don't see a clean way to do it though. (I realize this is sort of a different issue, but it is a big case that got me trying to figure this out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__new__`, but a factory function is the nice pythonic way to go.

Comment: So using a separate static method or function would be more pythonic than overriding __new__? Guess that counts as "simple is better than complex".

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into `__new__`. [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

Comment: Never thought of using __new__ for this. Would you essentially use __new__ as a factory function that has the possibility of returning instances of a subclass of cls?

Comment: It's definitely an approach worth pursuing. In the docs it mentions that if you return an an instance of a different class to the one in which `__new__` is defined `__init__` won't be called on the returned object. That suggests to me that this strategy is not severely 'frown upon' (if at all).

Answer (score 1):

In his [*Advanced C++ Programming Styles and Idioms*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201548550) book, James Coplien discusses how to simulate [virtual constructors](http://users.rcn.com/jcoplien/Patterns/C++Idioms/EuroPLoP98.html#VirtualConstructor) in C++ ([pdf version](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5508445/stackoverflow/C%2B%2B%20Idioms%20By%20James%20O.%20Coplien.pdf)). They have to be simulated because the language doesn't support them natively. This is where a call to a base class constructor results in a pointer to a subclass object being returned depending on the arguments passed (of course this only happens when you dynamically allocate and create an object using C++'s **new** operator).

I've found it possible to implement many of the concepts presented in Python, especially since, unlike in C++, classes are first class objects in Python and it has metaclasses.

Essentially the base class constructor becomes a factory function, and as in any factory function, it takes extra effort to make them extensible...in the sense that they don't have to know about every possible subclass that might be derived later. While some limitations exist with this approach, many useful applications are possible (and yours sounds like it might be one of them to me).